# Проблемы с настройкой формы обработки в 1С Предприятии

Tags: битрикс, 1с, битрикс24

Только начал изучать 1С и при просмотре видео-курса на YouTube, создается форма в которой можно выбрать тип формы, а у меня нельзя такого сделать, хотя обе версии учебные. Может быть, надо что-то изменить в настройках, но я не знаю как? Как показана на картинах, нужно добавить выбор тип формы. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вы добавляете форму?

Comment: Я захожу в файл -> новый -> внешняя обработка, и дальше при добавлении формы не получается выбрать тип формы.

Comment: Платформа учебная? Какая версия?

Comment: 1С:Предприятие 8.3, учебная версия (8.3.23.1688)

Comment: Странно. Попробуйте другую версию, может глюк.